# Finding source code for login

Tags: linux, authentication

I set

```
"user1 hard maxlogins 2"
```

i found "logged in as user1 twice" While logging for third time it said "Too many logins" - So i logged out "logout" from previous two logins ...even now it says the same error msg

I can verify this using "who" command running as root and check pam.d/login looks fine too.

I think ,its bug with login binary where can i found source for both login and limits.conf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my ubuntu system:

```
apt-file search /bin/login
```

gives:

```
gforge-web-apache2: /usr/share/gforge/www/scm/viewvc/bin/loginfo-handler
login: /bin/login
userful-multiplier: /opt/userful/bin/login-server
```

so, on debian based distros, you can get the source for the "login" package:

```
apt-get source login
```

**Edit**
Seems the actual package name is "shadow".